# Determine whether array key value is blank

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below, as you can see the last array [adad] value is blank, how can I write an if statement to tell whether this is blank.

```
Array
    (
        [K] => Array
            (
                [0] => mabel__chan
                [1] => mabel chan
            )

        [B] => Array
            (
                [0] => kieron br
            )

        [C] => Array
            (
                [0] => a br
                [1] => a
            )

        [adad] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

    )
```

**I have tried doing this**

```
if (count(array_filter($array)) == 0) {}
```

**Pseudo code**

```
if(array[key] == blank) {
  echo "is blank";
} else {
  echo "isn't blank";
}
```

**PHP Script this is how I get my data from mongoDB*
The answer below is working correctly when I use echos but now when I'm trying to push into new arrays its broken somewhere I get no data back anymore.

```
$col = "A" . $user->agencyID;
$db = $m->rules;
$collection = $db->$col;

$id = $_POST['ruleID'];

$search = array(
  '_id' => new MongoId($id)
);

$cursor = $collection->find($search);

$validTagsArray = array();
$validArray = array();

foreach ($cursor as $key => $value) {
  $temp = array_walk($array, function($v, $k) {
    if (count(array_filter($v)) === 0) {
      foreach ($value['AutoFix'] as $keyTwo => $valTwo) {
        $x = 0;
        $validTagsArray['data'][] = array($keyTwo, $x);
      }  
    } else {
      foreach ($value['AutoFix'] as $keyTwo => $valTwo) {
        $x = 0;
        foreach ($valTwo as $key => $value) {
          $x++;      
        }
        $validTagsArray['data'][] = array($keyTwo, $x);
      }            
    }
  });
}

echo json_encode($validTagsArray);
```

Comment: You can use if(empty($arr[$key])).

Comment: Have your tryed == "" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$array = array
(
    'K' => array('0' => 'mabel__chan','1' => 'mabel chan'),
    'B' => array('0' => 'kieron br'),
    'C' => array('0' => 'a br', '1' => 'a'),
    'adad' => array('0' => '')
);

$temp = array_walk($array, function($v, $k) {
    if(count(array_filter($v)) === 0) { // check the count of non-empty elements in the sub array
        echo $k . ' is empty';
    }
});
```

**Output**

```
adad is empty
```

Comment: Okay so it worked when I was using echos but has broke my php script now, I can't seem to figure out where though? (I have included the whole script in my post)

Comment: Broke? What error you are getting? Can't help without code.

Comment: `array_walk` doesn't work that way. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php. You should have added the proper question. And also you should read about the **scope** of variables.

Comment: Your answer was what I asked though just after using it I have created an error.

Answer (score 0):

**You can write as:**

```
if([adad][0]== " ")
 {

 }
```

You can also try this :

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
   if(empty($value))
     echo "empty";
   }
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.